# jQuery UI : sortable and draggable behaviour while dropping object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When working with jQuery sortable, draggable and dropable.

1. Dropping a sortable item in sortable.
2. Dropping a draggable in a droppable.

The container in which we are dropping any object, only accepts it if the center position of that object lies in the bounderies of container.

Sorry the above statement is too much complex please see below picture.

How can we change the point of acceptance?

[image]

Comment: I think its bit difficult to understand my question, but i am here to clear any doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `tolerance` option ([droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance), [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-tolerance)).

- `droppable()` supports `fit`, `intersect`, `pointer` and `touch`.
- `sortable()` only supports `intersect` and `pointer`.

`intersect` is the default for both widgets.

Comment: + 1, Thanks @Hamidi for your response. After reading the options i am pretty confident that this is my answer. I will update after i test it.